# Primefaces editor generates span elements

Tags: jsf, primefaces, editor

I use primefaces editor within a project (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/editor.xhtml). My problem is that it always generates SPAN elements.

E.g. **test** is exported as

```
<span style="font-weight: bold;">test</span>
```

Instead of this, I need to generate  markup (and so for the other functions) liek this:

```
<b>test</b>
```

Any idea?

(it is not my personal wish but a need to be compatible with a legacy API)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<p:editor>` use `<pe:ckEditor>`  primefaces extension, and there are various options available for this choose according to your requirement primefaces editor will always generate span for text.